# How to automatically "load more" at the end of a mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, web-applications

How could I fire an ajax request automatically at the end of a **mobile** page (with jquery and jquery mobile)? The code

```
$(document).bind('pageshow #item_search', function(){
        $('#content_table').scroll(function() {
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
               //ajax
               alert("end of page");
           }
        });
});
```

works great on a desktop PC, but does nothing on my phone...

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879417/how-to-capture-scroll-start-event-on-iphone-android

Comment: thanks, but that is not the same because the code in the answer fires everytime the user scrolls, even if he is miles away from the bottom of the page...

Comment: Are the right events but you must check if you are at the bottom, like what you do in the scroll event

Answer (score 2):

Here's an working example : [**http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/v4NxB/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/v4NxB/).

I made it as proof of concept so it is far from perfect demo but it can give you enough info to use it correctly.

It uses this jQuery plugin called **[Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started)** to detect bottom scroll touch

I have built it with jQM 1.0 so I can't tell you if it is going to work with jQuery Mobile 1.3.1.

This will detect bottom end:

```
$('#example-offset-pixels').waypoint(function() {
    //notify('100 pixels from the top');
}, { offset: 100 });
```

There also another solution I used to use but it is not mine. It was originally used in some previous **[Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752738/jasper)** answer.

This version works with every jQM version, including 1.3 : [**http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Bn2Du/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Bn2Du/). It uses pure jQuery, no need for additional frameworks. I have tested it on iPad and Android devices.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't want to use plugins, so i've done the "load-more"-thing now with a plain and simple "load-more"-button :) didn't know that the procedure is _that_ complicated on a mobile phone

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Mobile [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html) for events suggest to use scrollstart & scrollstop. Try:

```
$('#content_table').bind("scrollstop", function() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
         alert("end of page");
     }
});
```

Or you could combine scrollstart/scrollstop with touchmove to try and get real-time events:

```
$('#content_table').bind("scrollstart", function() {
     $(this).bind("touchmove", function() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
             alert("end of page");
         }
     }
}).bind("scrollend", function() {
     $(this).unbind("touchmove");
});
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. without the `if window scrollTop()` math inside the brackets the code works, but in a wrong way (it fires everytime a scroll stops).

Comment: See updated answer. You can combine the three events of, scrollstart - start monitoring for changes, touchmove - check the scroll position when the user moves their finger, scrollend - unbind from the scrollstart event

Comment: do you mean `.bind("scrollstop", function()` instead of `scrollend`? i've changed that but this code gives me an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" error in my console...

Comment: hm thanks for your answer, but it don't works. i've done the "load-more"-thing now with a plain and simple "load-more"-button :) didn't know that the procedure is that complicated on a mobile phone :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use JQM:
It was a long time to find a way to find good code, to recognize bottom of the page, and to load more content.

Finally i used this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()) {
    NameFunctionWhatCallsAjax();
   }
});
```

And I put this in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It works on Iphone and other mobile devices too.
in NameFunctionWhatCallsAjax(); function you call make for example ajax call for new rows.
I hope it will work for you too.

And in ajax success put for example:

```
              success: function(response){
        $('#loading').remove();
            $('.infinite-container').append(response);
        $('.infinite-container').append("<li id='loading'>Lo9ading new rows..</li>");
            $('.infinite-container').listview('refresh');
          }
```

You need to refresh to have the same visual look like jquery mobile have because of jquery mobile themes.